# send a second request after the first is completed

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a method (requestData) that can be called several times in my ViewController but the first time the ViewController is loaded (in ViewDidLoad method) I need to call it two times BUT the second request should be sent only after the first request has completed:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    dataForPlot = 1;
    [self requestData: dataForPlot];

    dataForPlot = 2;
    [self requestData: dataForPlot];
}

- (void) requestData: (int) forPlot  {
    ... 
    [urlRequest startWithCompletion:^(URLRequest *request, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL success) {

    if (success) {

       if (forPlot == 1) {      
       ...
       }

       else if (forPlot == 2) {
       ...
       }
    }
}
```

I know I probably need to use blocks but, even if I've tried to read some tutorials, I don't know how.

Anyone could help me ?

Thanks, Corrado

Here is what I've implemented following Duncan suggestion:

```
typedef void(^myCompletion)(BOOL);

- (void)viewDidLoad {     
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self requestData:^(BOOL finished) {    // first request

       if(finished) {
          NSLog(@"send second request");
          [self requestData: ^(BOOL finished) {}];  // second request
       }
    }];


- (void) requestData: (myCompletion) compblock {
    ...
    [urlRequest startWithCompletion:^(URLRequest *request, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL success) {

    if (success) {
    ...

    NSLog(@"request completed");
    compblock(YES);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor your requestData method to take a completion block.

In your requestData method, When the url request completes, invoke the completion block.

In viewDidLoad, use a completion block that calls requestData a second time, this time with an empty completion block.

In your other calls to the requestData method, pass in a nil completion block (or whatever other action you need to trigger when the request finishes)

Comment: Thanks, I suppose this is the right solution but I'm having some problems in writing the code (blocks are so hard to use)  ... would it be possible to have some help in implementing your suggestion ?

Comment: Post what you're trying as an edit to your original question, along with the problems you're having with it.

Comment: It seems I've finally found something that works (see my edited question) ... would appreciate if you could confirm I did it right. Thanks !

Comment: Yup, your new code looks reasonable. I also still have trouble with block syntax sometimes BTW. Powerful but ugly.

Answer (score 3):

Don't call the second request until the first completes:

```
- (void) requestData: (int) forPlot  {
    ... 
    [urlRequest startWithCompletion:^(URLRequest *request, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL success) {

    if (success) {

       if (forPlot == 1) {      
           ...
           dataForPlot = 2;
           [self requestData: dataForPlot];

       }

       else if (forPlot == 2) {
           ...
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I've already tried but in this way EVERY TIME (not just when I call it from viewDidLoad) I call the method with forPlot = 1, the method is called again with forPlot = 2. Is there any other solution that would avoid this ?

Comment: If you don't want to *always* do this, you should use the solution suggested by Duncan C.